# How to delete a commit after "sharing a new project using SVN" Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

I want to synchronize my existing project with the same in SVN, so I make

- Team-> Share Project,
- enter my SVN repository url
- in the last dialog window, SVN ask me to enter commit body
- press OK.

(the same steps as here -> https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/sharing_wiz.php )

How to roll-back this commit? I don't see this commit in Team -> Show History

Comment: Something is wrong. If your project already exists in SVN, you should not have been asked to enter a commit message. How did you get your project out of SVN to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a commit from history, but it is pretty easy to undo the effects of the commit.  Here are a couple of blog posts I have written in the past that explain how to do it:

[Second Chances and Subversion](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/second-chances)

[How to Undo a Commit in Subversion](http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-to-undo-commit-in-subversion.html)

The second of those in particular show how to do it via Subclipse GUI (as it existed back in 2007).